# Putting data in DataGrid using AS3 Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, datagrid, mxml, dataprovider

I have a simple array of objects:

public var activityArray:Array=["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"];

How would I basically put this into a data-grid column? I have set up the datagrid as part of it is shown below:

```
 </mx:HBox>
    <components:PortalTabGridCanvas id="marketPlansGridCanv" height="33%" width="98.5%">
        <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="marketPlansGrid" height="100%" width="100%" dataProvider="activityArray">
            <mx:columns>    
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="{Mlc.curr.get('Activity Type')}" width="160" dataField="ATTRIB_VALUE" textAlign="center" headerWordWrap="true"/>

                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="{Mlc.curr.get('Activity')}" width="160" dataField="ATTRIB_VALUE" textAlign="center" headerWordWrap="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataGrid` is designed to inspect `Object`s and extract data from that `Object`s readable properties, as you are using `String`s in your `dataProvider`, there are no properties to read.

To display data from an `Object` in an `AdvancedDataGridColumn`, the columns [`dataField`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridColumn.html#dataField) must be the name a readable property from that `Object`.

You would need to define your `dataProvider` to contain `Object`s at a minimum like the below example.

```
public var activityArray:Array = 
[
    {
        property1:"a1",
        property2:"a1's second property"
    } ,
    {
        property1:"a2",
        property2:"a2's second property"
    } 
//etc, etc, etc...
];
```

And then define your columns like:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="{Mlc.curr.get('Activity Type')}" width="160" dataField="property1" textAlign="center" headerWordWrap="true"/>
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="{Mlc.curr.get('Activity')}" width="160" dataField="property2" textAlign="center" headerWordWrap="true"/>
```